# Downgrade SQL database to the client sql server version

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, desktop-application

I've create a desktop app in C# win Form after publish it it's work just fine in my system but when installed in the client system it shows this error message

> the database 'database path\database.mdf' cannot be opened because it
> is version 904, This server supports 782 and earlier, A downgrade path
> is not supported.

I tried to change the compatibility level to 100 which what SQL server 2008 support and rebuild the the app and check if the database has really changed the level to 100 and it does so after republish still shows the same error.

So is there a proper way to downgrade the database or make a second copy that the system choose what its compatible with?

note : I create the database with SQL Server 2019 which a Level 150
the client Has a windows 7 laptop and only SQL Server 2014 and earlier can be installed.

Comment: You cannot restore a database on an older version of SQL Server. You will need to script the database out if you want it on an older version.

Comment: *"the client Has a windows 7 laptop"* Get them to update; Windows 7 hasn't been supported for years.

Comment: @Larnu so you mean , I have to script it and take all the data and recreated it to an older version basically Create a new database ? 
For the windows 7 thing try to convince him that xD

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I am saying; SQL Server isn't forward compatible, only backwards. The alternative would be to say the client needs to use SQL Server 2019+, which would mandate they use a supported operating system

Comment: Considering that LocalDB and Express Editions are free, client should just upgrade to 2019. Note that the compatibility level is irrelevant, that is only so that you can run older code on the newer version

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script for your database and define the server this script should target. New database script will create the `database.mdf` file compatible with client.

Here are the steps.

1. Right click on your Database and select `Tasks > Generate Scripts...`

[image: Generate Scripts...]

2. Click "Next" and then "Advanced"

[image: Step2]

3. From "Script for Server Version" dropdown select your desired server

[image: Step3]

4. A script for that version of sql Database will be generated and save at given directory. You can run that script on your end to create an mdf and share with client to use as localDB or simply run the script on client's instance